# Pettis integrability condition

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $B$ be a Banach Space, $(X,\mu)$ a measure space and $f:X\longrightarrow B$ a weak measurable function, that is a function such that:
$$ \phi\circ f:X \longrightarrow \mathbb C $$
is measurable forall $\phi\in B^*$ (the topological dual).

If $||f(x)||\leq M(x)$ with $M\in L^1$, can we deduce that $f$ is Pettis integrable?

Comment: If $B$ is separable and $f$ is strongly measurable $\big(f^{-1}(U)$ is measurable for every onen subset $U\subseteq B\big)$ then $f$ is actually Bochner integrable and hence also Pettis integrable.

Comment: Thanks. I know that but I want to allow $B$ or $f(X)$ be non-separable. My motivation are the unitary group representations $p:G\longrightarrow U(H)$, (and I don't want to suppose $H$ to be separable).

Comment: I guess only representations of compact groups would satisfy your last condition, in which case they will be Bochner integrable.

Comment: Do you mean that only the compact group representation are strongly measurable (Borel measurable and $p(G)$ dense)? Sorry, I didn't understand you

Comment: I meant the last condition, namely $\|f(x)\|\leq M(x)$, with $M$ in $L^1$. The point is that the total Haar measure of non-compact groups is infinite.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I mean integrals of kind $\int_GF(x)\pi(x)dg(x)$ for $F\in L^1(G)$ or integrals of one parameter groups $V:\mathbb R \longrightarrow U(H)$ in a finite interval (which are related with group representations). If $\pi$ or $V$ are continuos with respect the strong operator topology and $H$ is separable, I can integrate them: for example, $u \mapsto \int_G F(x) \pi(x) u dg(x)$ (using the Bochner integral here) defines a bounded operator.

Comment: Can you prove that $x\mapsto F(x)\pi(x)$ is weakly measurable?  I worry because the dual of $B{H)$ is huge!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself very well. I didn't consider the Pettis integral for $F(x)\pi(x)$. I only considered the Bochner integral of $F(x)\pi(x)u$, $u\in H$ if $H$ is separable. If $H$ were not separable, I would like to know if $F(x)u$ is Pettis integrable and if the Pettis integral defines a bounded operator.

Comment: I finally see. A suficient condition of $B$ is to be reflexive, because the functional $\phi\mapsto \int\phi\circ f$ is an element of $(B^*)^*$. The application I've just mention it's more direct, $F(x)(\pi(x)u,v)$ is integrable and the map $g(u,v)=\int F(x)(\pi(x)u,v)$ is a bounded sesquilinear form, so there is a unique operator $g(u,v)=(Au,v)$. What about we can say if $B$ is not reflexive or separable? I think maybe f is not Pettis integrable...

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bf}[1]{\mathbb #1}\newcommand{\sc}[1]{\mathscr #1}$The answer is affirmative for separable Banach spaces.

In order to prove it, consider the linear functional $\Lambda $ defined on the (topological) dual space $B'$  by
$$
  \Lambda (\varphi )=\int_X \varphi \big (f(x)\big )\, d\mu (x), \quad\forall \varphi \in B'.
  $$
Notice that
the integrand satisfies
$$
  |\varphi \big (f(x)\big )| \leq  \|\varphi \| \|f(x)\| \leq  \|\varphi \| M(x),
  $$
so
$$
  |\Lambda (\varphi )|\leq \|\varphi \|\|M\|_1,\quad\forall \varphi \in B',
  $$
and hence  $\Lambda $ is seen to be continuous.  We next claim that $\Lambda $ is also continuous relative to  the
weak-star topology on $B'$.

Using
V.12.8 in Conway's "A Course in Functional Analysis", a Corollary of Krein-Smulian's Theorem,  it is enough to show that $\Lambda $ is weak-star *sequentially*
continuous.   So let us suppose that $\{\varphi _n\}_n$ is a sequence in $B'$ converging to some $\varphi \in B'$ relatively to  weak-star topology.

If tollows that
$$
  \varphi _n\circ f \to  \varphi \circ f
  $$ pointwise everywhere on $X$.  Moreover, by the Banach-Steinhauss Theorem, we have that the $\varphi _n$ are uniformly
bounded, whence
$$
  K := \sup_{n\in {\bf N}}\|\varphi _n\| <\infty ,
  $$
and hence
$$
  |\varphi _n(f(x))| \leq  \|\varphi _n\| \|f(x)\| \leq   K M(x),\quad \forall x \in X.
  $$
We may then  use Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem to conclude that
$$
  \lim_{n\to \infty } \Lambda (\varphi _n) =
  \lim_{n\to \infty } \int_X \varphi _n(f(x))\, d\mu (x) = $$$$ =
  \int_X \varphi (f(x))\, d\mu (x) = \Lambda (\varphi ),
  $$
hence concluding the proof of the weak-star continuity of $\Lambda $.

As it is well known, every weak-star continuous linear functional on $B'$ must be a point-evaluation, so there exists
$b\in B$ such that
$$
  \Lambda (\varphi )= \varphi (b),\quad\forall \varphi \in B'.
  $$
Consequently
$$
  \int_X \varphi (f(x))\, d\mu (x) = \varphi (b),
  $$
so $f$ is Pettis integrable!

---

Thanks to MathOverflow user @Mikael de la Sale for pointing me towards Krein-Smulian's Theorem!